# Script to download and extract zip files returns errors

Tags: php, zip, archive

Hey everyone, I have written a script that downloads a zip file from a remote source, and then is supposed to extract the zip file to a directory. Below is the script:

```
    <?php
        $url = "http://example.com/some_file.zip";
        download($url,'file.zip');

        function download($url,$file_name = NULL){
          if($file_name == NULL){ $file_name = basename($url);}

          $url_stuff = parse_url($url);
          $port = isset($url_stuff['port']) ? $url_stuff['port'] : 80;

          $fp = fsockopen($url_stuff['host'], $port);
          if(!$fp){ return false;}

          $query  = 'GET ' . $url_stuff['path'] . " HTTP/1.0\n";
          $query .= 'Host: ' . $url_stuff['host'];
          $query .= "\n\n";

          fwrite($fp, $query);

          while ($tmp = fread($fp, 8192))   {
            $buffer .= $tmp;
          }

          preg_match('/Content-Length: ([0-9]+)/', $buffer, $parts);
          $file_binary = substr($buffer, - $parts[1]);
          if($file_name == NULL){
            $temp = explode(".",$url);
            $file_name = $temp[count($temp)-1];
          }
          if(!file_exists("packages")){ mkdir("packages", 0755);}
          $file_open = fopen("packages/" . $file_name,'w');
          if(!$file_open){ return false;}
          fwrite($file_open,$file_binary);

          $zip = zip_open(realpath("packages")."/".$file_name);
          if ($zip) {
            while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
              $fp = fopen("some_dir/".zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
              if(zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
                $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
                fwrite($fp,"$buf");
                zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                fclose($fp);
              }
            }
            zip_close($zip);
          }
          fclose($file_open);
          return true;
        }
   ?>
```

The issue that I have is that while the downloading of the remote file works flawlessly, I can't seem to extract it. The `zip_read()` and `zip_close()` return errors saying that it "expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given...", which I have found means that the `zip_open()` was unable to extract and is returning an error code, which I have found to be "19" meaning "Zip File Function error: Not a zip archive". However, I know the file I am downloading is, in fact, a zip file. Can anyone explain this odd behavior and provide a fix? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should `fclose($file_open)` before doing the zip operations. You don't need the `$file_open` handle anymore at that point, and keeping two handles on the same file is messy. I don't think that's the cause of the problem though.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, thanks for help cleaning up. But yes, as you suggested the problem was not changed by this at all.

Comment: BTW I really appreciate the effort to delve into HTTP this way, but have you looked into using `file_get_contents("http://.../")`, `curl_open`, etc etc?

Comment: There is a list of error codes in a comment to the zip constants page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php  (I don't know that they're correct, but it could be useful.)

Comment: @mvds I have not yet, however it may be somewhere I need to go. It would probably save some headaches now and in the future. I've never done any type of work with getting/reading remote files before, so I'm learning a bit as I go. I'll look at those two options. I've heard great things about curl before.


@George Thanks for the info, looks great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting php.net: "zip_open() ... Returns a resource handle for later use with zip_read() and zip_close()  or returns the number of error if filename does not exist or in case of other error."

This means you cannot test `if ($zip)` like that. Try

```
if ( is_resource($zip) ) {
    // stuff
} else {
    print "Zip_open() returned error $zip\n";
}
```

**edit:** Apart from that, you need to cut the response in 2 parts properly. You are relying heavily on the `Content-Length` parameter. You don't check if the `preg_match` actually matched. A lot of things can go wrong and you should check those things. Try splitting the content on the first empty line (`explode` on `\r\n\r\n` or something like that)

Besides the `fread()` loop should check for `feof()`, since you would stop reading now if for some reason you would encounter an empty read. Copy&paste from php.net:

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
```

But we can go on and on here. Three main points have to be made:

- read the fantastic manual (php.net)
- check return values
- don't assume you know things you don't

those are related: you must lookup the manual to see what return values you might encounter.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I have made the change, however now instead of printing the errors, it will just skip the extraction part because the zip_open still can't open the zip file. So this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ben Then figure out why it's not opening the file.  For example, is `realpath("packages")."/".$file_name` the correct path?

Comment: Well honestly I thought it was something in my code, maybe that it was downloading incorrectly? That's why I included that download section. I think this because I have issues when opening the file with a file manager, it says the zip format is invalid. However I can still open it with 7-zip, so it must be something with the format. I know that its not the original file however, because if I download it on my computer and extract it it works fine. I have also tested it with the wordpress zip file for example, so its not that.

Comment: have you downloaded the file that has been stored by this script? If so, `zip_open` may either just be a little pickier than your average unzip program, or it is a zip format which is not supported by php's `zip_open`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that must be what it is. Its just pickier/doesn't support the zip format. Thanks for the help and the suggestions on how to clean up my code.