# PHP handles a zip file as if it's empty

Tags: php, zip

Here's a very stripped down version of the code I'm using.

```
$url = "http://server.com/getDaFile";

//Get the file from the server
$zip_file_contents = file_get_contents($url);
//Write file to disk
file_put_contents("file.zip", $zip_file_contents);

//open zip file
$zip = zip_open("file.zip");

if(is_resource($zip))
{
    while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
    {
        if(zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, 'r'))
        {
            //Read the whole file
            $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            /*
            Do stuff with $buf!!!
            */

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }
    }

    zip_close($zip);
}
else
{
    echo "Not a resource. Oh noes!\n";
}
```

So : get the file, save it to disk, unzip it to extract files it contains, do stuff with files. The problem here is that, for some reason I cannot figure out, `zip_read` returns `FALSE`, as if it couldn't read files inside the ZIP archive. `$zip` does contain a resource, I've checked with `var_dump`.

What makes this even stranger is that I downloaded the ZIP file on my PC using the URL on top, manually uploaded it to the PHP server, and commented out the calls to `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` so PHP uses the local version. When I do this, `zip_read` correctly finds the right amount of files inside the ZIP and processing proceeds as it should.

I also tried doing this : `$zip = zip_open($url)` but `$zip` fails the `is_resource($zip)` check.

Something is obviously wrong with my code since the URL works and returns a valid ZIP archive. What is it?

Comment: did you bother checking if f_g_c() actually got something, like `echo strlen($zipfile_contents)`? That fact that it works on your pc doesn't mean much. totally different environments.

Comment: Your comment about different environments is right, @MarcB. As for `$zipfile_contents`, echoing its contents displays a large amount of gibberish (as expected from a ZIP file), but that gibberish contains the name of the files I'm looking for towards the end.

Comment: zip_open returns either a resource or an error number. you should have `if is_resource() { else echo $zip }` type thing to see what that error number is (if any). don't see anything in the online docs what the codes are, but they'd be in the php-zip source somewhere.

Comment: Edited code accordingly (I even added a var_dump on my side inside the `if is_resource()` check to make sure, it displays `resource(161, Zip Directory)`) and the check does pass, so it really is a resource I'm dealing with.

Comment: It seems like the ZIP file is getting corrupt. Can you run an `md5_file()` on the file that is downloaded by the script and compare the hash with that of the version you downloaded yourself. Can you also provide the real file URL for us to test?

Comment: Sort of unrelated but you could use `file_put_contents("file.zip", fopen("http://server.com/getDaFile", "r"));` or perhaps `copy("http://server.com/getDaFile", "file.zip");` as these will transfer the file without storing it all in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found out the problem. Following @diolemo's suggestion, I opened my server's ZIP archive in a hex editor. Here's what I found at the top, followed by the usual ZIP binary data : http://pastebin.com/vQEXJtTN

It turns out there was a PHP error mixed in with the actual content of the ZIP file. Unsure of how to fix this (but knowing it certainly had to do with HTTP headers), I tried [this guy's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349225/script-to-download-and-extract-zip-files-returns-errors) and, what do you know, my code works perfectly now!

Lessons learned? Never trust your data, even if it seems all right (both 7-Zip and Winrar managed to open the file without problem).